# Updating a N-1 columns of a N columned table using QueryOver<T>() method

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I want to update only some columns say N-1 columns in a table containing N columns using NHibernate QueryOver syntax.

The query I tried is something like this.

```
    public T UpdatePost(Object DateUpdated, object DateExpires, object Id)
    {
        using (var session=sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var transaction=session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Update(DateUpdated, Id);
                session.Update(DateExpires, Id);
                transaction.Commit();
                return session.Get<T>(Id);
            }
        }
    }
```

Calling method is

```
obj.UpdatePost(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(30), 3);
```

Error is

> There is a problem with your mappings.  You are probably trying to map a System.ValueType to a  which NHibernate does not allow or you are incorrectly using the IDictionary that is mapped to a .  A ValueType (System.DateTime) can not be used with IdentityKey.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Your `UpdatePost` method makes no sense. NHibernate's `session.Update` expects an entity object that should be updated. Documentation for the overload you are trying to use is:

> Updates the persistent state associated with the given identifier.

First argument should be an entire entity object.

If you try to analyze your code, there's no way for NHibernate to know which entity do you want to update. `Update` method is not generic, neither is the `Session`. You are just trying to give it a date value and an id. How would NHibernate know which table and which column to update?

In order to do partial updates with NHibernate, you would need to use [HQL update queries](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-direct) (DML-style operations).

Here's how it would look like in your case:

```
public T UpdatePost(Object DateUpdated, object DateExpires, object Id)
{
    using (var session=sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        using (var transaction=session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            string hqlUpdate = 
                 "update Post p set p.DateUpdated = :dateUpdated, p.DateExpires = :dateExpires where p.id = :id";
            session.CreateQuery(hqlUpdate)
                   .SetDateTime("dateUpdated", DateUpdated)
                   .SetDateTime("dateExpires", DateExpires)
                   .SetParameter("id", Id)
                   .ExecuteUpdate();
            transaction.Commit();
            return session.Get<T>(Id);
        }
    }
}
```

On a side note, since you are already getting the entity itself after the update, you could simply load the entity first, change its properties and save it. You would still have two database operations.

```
public T UpdatePost(DateTime DateUpdated, DateTime DateExpires, object Id)
{
    using (var session=sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        using (var transaction=session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            T post = session.Get<T>(Id);
            post.DateUpdated = DateUpdated;
            post.DateExpires = DateExpires;
            session.Update(post);
            transaction.Commit();
            return post;
        }
    }
}
```

If you *really* want to force NHibernate to update only the columns that are changed, you can specify dynamic-update="true" in [class mapping declaration](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-class).

> **dynamic-update (optional, defaults to false)**: Specifies that UPDATE SQL should be generated at runtime and contain only those columns whose values have changed.

Comment: Hi Miroslav, SetDateTime method does not accept objects as parameter values as we are passing DateUpdated, DateExpires.`public T UpdatePost(Object DateUpdated, object DateExpires, object Id)` however I'm declaring the method generically we must provide the type of entity. your second solution was applicable to entity specific repositories. Kindly see my answer for solution which I found out after forking google for a couple of hours.

Comment: Ah, ok... You might have tried using `.SetParameter()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This will be the optimal solution as SetDateTime accepts only DateTime types as its parameter values. and while declaring this method generically, we must format the query according to its entity type.

```
public T UpdatePost(DateTime DateUpdated, DateTime DateExpires, object Id) <-- DateTime parameters
        {
            using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
            {
                using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    string hqlUpdate = string.Format(
                 "update {0} p set p.DateUpdated = :dateUpdated, p.DateExpires = :dateExpires where p.id = :id", typeof(T)); <-- passing the type of the entity.
                    session.CreateQuery(hqlUpdate)
                           .SetDateTime("dateUpdated",DateUpdated)
                           .SetDateTime("dateExpires", DateExpires)
                           .SetParameter("id", Id)
                           .ExecuteUpdate();
                    transaction.Commit();
                    return session.Get<T>(Id);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is `Post` a base class in your domain? Not sure why would the method be named `UpdatePost` and generic at the same time.

Comment: Post is not a base class. That's why I've removed post and formated it as typeof(T) ie it corresponds to every entity. In my database each and every table (Entity) contains DateUpdated and DateExpires columns. That's why I am writing the Update Post method at repository level instead of entity level. And this funtionality just updates both times but no other columns are affected.